# VSCode showing weird errors in my Haxe Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, haxe

i just started learning Haxe today and i got a couple of problems with my VSCode.

There are 3 "Errors" in total, to be exact 2 errors and 1 info, but the info seems kind of wrong and i would like to know how to get rid of it aswell.

Before i go into more detail, some info that might be relevant:

- I created my project using the "Haxe: Initialize Project" from the Haxe VSCode extension
- I changed nothing in the build.hxml file
- If i run my code via VSCode (Ctrl-Shift-B) i get an error
- If i run it on a normal CMD with "haxe build.hxml" it works totally fine, no errors at all

**The Code:**

```
class Main {
     static function main() {
          trace("Hello, World!");
          var t:String = Sys.stdin().readLine().toString();
          trace(t);
     }
}
```

**The build.hxml file:**

```
-cp src
-D analyzer-optimize
-main Main
--interp
```

**The first error i get:**

It seems that this error is not even in my own file, how can this be?
The `Sys.stdin().readLine()` seems to have something to do with it, since this error came the moment i added this line.

```
Uncaught exception Not implemented in haxe.io.input.readByte at haxe/io/Input.hx tasks [180. 1]
```

[Screenshot from VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiK0W.png)

**The second error i get:**

Once again it seems to have something to do with `Sys.stdin().readline()` this time this exact part of my code is red underlined and the error message is pointing at this exact line.

`Called from here tasks  [4, 18]`

[Screenshot from VSCode (Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvwJU.png)
[Screenshot from VSCode (red underline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNRtv.png)

**The (kind of) error / Info i get:**

This is the most weird one imho..
Its a blue "~" i get at the beginning of my `trace("Hello, World!");` line.

[Screenshot from the weird Blue Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpm1Y.png)
[Screenshot from the VSCode "Problem" regarding this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQvm7.png)

**Thanks in advance!**

I looked through the internet the whole day hoping to find something to get this things solved on my own, but since its my first time ever using Haxe and i was not able to find something even similar to this i hope some of you 5heads out there can help me with this. :)